# If statement for ListBox1.SelectedItem

Tags: vb.net, selected, listboxitem

I keep getting errors when i try and click an item on the listbox and then try and run the code. It tells me something about converting it to a boolean but i'm not entirely sure. I tried ToString() but to no luck.

I dont want the code to run unless something is selected inside of the Listbox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If ListBox1.SelectedItem Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Enabled = False

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        TextBox1.Text &= "Preparing"
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        TextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & ""
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        TextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & ""

    Else
        MsgBox("", 0, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your first IF statement. It doesn't make sense the way it's written. Do you want to go in if an item is selected and in the else if nothing is selected?

Comment: If `Option Strict` was `On` this code couldn't even compile saying that it don't know how to cast Object to Boolean in the If line (and that would have been a big clue of what is the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox.SelectedItem` returns the actual selected item in the ListBox, but an If statement requires an expression to evaluate to a Boolean (true or false). What you're looking for is probably:

```
If (ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then ....
```

Also your if you are using doesn't amount to anything except to `True` you may want to change this...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, my assumption is that you only want to execute the conditional code if `ListBox1` has a selected item. But the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property can't be used as a boolean like that.

Instead, consider just checking the selected index of the ListBox, like:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
    [...]
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you'd like to retain more of your current code, you could make your condition into a comparison of the `SelectedItem` against `Nothing`:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    [...]
```